# Can a missed approach be used to satisfy the requirements for the long cross country as part of an instrument rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, instrument-flight-rules, instrument-rating

The long cross country requirements are as follows:

> §61.65(d)(2)
>
> (ii) Instrument flight training on cross country flight procedures, including one cross country flight in an airplane with an authorized instructor, that is performed under instrument flight rules, when a flight plan has been filed with an air traffic control facility, and that involves -
>
> (A) A flight of 250 nautical miles along airways or by directed routing from an air traffic control facility;
>
> (B) An instrument approach at each airport; and
>
> (C) Three different kinds of approaches with the use of navigation
> systems.

I flew from my base airport, a 100nm leg, performed an RNAV approach to land, departed on another 100nm leg, performed an ILS approach to land, departed on the last 100nm leg back to my base airport. There, while I flew the VOR approach past the FAF, we decided to go missed due to terrible wind gusts. We diverted VFR to a nearby airport and proceeded to land there.

Have I actually satisfied the requirements in §61.65(d)(2)(ii)(B) and (C)?

Comment: I vaguely recall reading (either here or on Reddit) about an interpretation that said something to the effect of: if you're in IMC past the FAF, you can go missed any time past the FAF and log the approach. If you're in VMC, you need to take the approach all the way to the DH/MDA/whatever in order to log the approach. Could be misremembering.

Comment: It was simulated instrument, but not actual IMC. Do you suppose that counts as IFR in VMC or IFR in IMC?

Comment: A poor example, but anyway: my first solo was cut short due to adverse weather closing in on the airport. I did not fly the "required" amount of touch and gos, but as everything else went smoothly, it was deemed a good performance as I appropriately used my judgement. I actually do not remember (and am too lazy to check) whether there are strict guidelines for the stuff one must do on a first solo...

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't count since you were passed the final approach fix. You would have switched to visuals once you have had the runway in sight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information in the FAA's  ["InFO15012"](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/info/all_infos/media/2015/info15012.pdf) document, dated 9/8/15 and Titled "Subject: Logging Instrument Approach Procedures (IAP)," it appears that under the circumstances you describe in your question "... *we decided to go missed due to terrible wind gusts*" you should be able to count/credit that IAP towards the requirements for your instrument rating.

Below, are two relevant excerpts from the **FAA InFO15012** document noted above. (*see the full document in the InFO15012 link in the first paragraph above*)

---

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Have you satisfied §61.65(d)(2)(ii)?

**Yes.**

I also looked to see that you made a landing at an airport beyond 50NM from the original point of departure.  It sounds like you did so it is a cross country flight.

The flight was conducted under IFR and coordination with ATC was necessary to conduct the missed approach and then cancel IFR and fly visually to the alternate.  An examiner, when looking at the logbooks, may ask you questions about that flight.  As long as you are forthright with the conditions of the flight should be no problem.

Comment: I would also suggest you ask the examiner you intend to administer your checkride.  If he is ok with it, then go for it.  After you're awarded the rating nobody is going to query whether you had satisfied the requirements of §61.65(d)(2)(ii).